# Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

Earlier my Android project was just working fine. But after updating the Client provided .aar library i am getting this error.

In our project we haven't used jacoco dependency anywhere

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline**;
        at com.airtel.middleware.managers.ImwInitialization.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.airtel.middleware.managers.ImwInitialization.getInstance(Unknown Source:3)
        **at com.airtel.fti.scan.ScanActivity2.onCreate(ScanActivity2.java:21)**
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/FTI_App_release_1.0.17.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib/FTI_App_release_1.0.17, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Can any one please help me to resolve this.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this. I am facing similar issue.

Comment: Same issue here. I built my AAR and then I'm getting the exact same error. Looks like is an issue with gradle

Answer (score 0):

On my case, the issue was on the AAR's build.

I realize gradle run this task when the AAR is being built:
[image: jacoco gradle task]

So I just deleted the entire build folder on the AAR project, rebuilt my AAR and reimport it on my other project.